# What com object name needs to be used when using Powershell in Windows Virtual XP Mode?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine

The following script does not work when executed using Powershell v2.0 in Windows Virtual XP Mode:

```
# Connect to Virtual PC
$vpc = new-object -comobject "VirtualPC.Application"

# Get VM name
$vmName = Read-host "Specify the name of the virtual machine that you want to use"

# List available USB devices
write-host "The following USB devices are available:"
$vpc.USBDeviceCollection | select -ExpandProperty DeviceString

# Get the USB device name
$usb = Read-host "Enter the name of the USB device that you want to connect to the virtual machine"

# Get the VM object
$vm = $vpc.findVirtualMachine($vmName)

# Get the USB object
$usbDevice = $vpc.USBDeviceCollection | ? {$_.DeviceString -eq $usb} | select -first 1

# Attach the device - this will fail if the VM is not running
$vm.AttachUSBDevice($usbDevice)
```

This instruction --> `$vpc = new-object -comobject "VirtualPC.Application"`
does not work in Windows Virtual XP Mode
What is the comobject that needs to be used in Windows Virtual XP Mode?

I have determined that this instruction --> `$vpc.USBDeviceCollection | select -ExpandProperty DeviceString`
needs to be replaced with this instruction --> `$vpc.IVMDeviceCollection | select -ExpandProperty DeviceString`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking in the registry in XP Mode? Only objects registered in the registry in the virtual machine can be created.

Comment: Where should I look in the registry in XP Mode?